# Map multiple objects to single object in stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-streams

I have some very large (> 500MB) JSON files that I need to map to a new format and upload to a new DB.

The old format:

```
{
    id: '001',
    timestamp: 2016-06-02T14:10:53Z,
    contentLength: 123456,
    filepath: 'original/...',
    size: 'original'
},
{
    id: '001',
    timestamp: 2016-06-02T14:10:53Z,
    contentLength: 24565,
    filepath: 'medium/...',
    size: 'medium'
},
{
    id: '001',
    timestamp: 2016-06-02T14:10:53Z,
    contentLength: 5464,
    filepath: 'small/...',
    size: 'small'
}
```

The new format:

```
{
    Id: '001',
    Timestamp: 2016-06-02T14:10:53Z,
    OriginalSize: {
        ContentLength: 123456,
        FilePath: 'original/...'
    },
    MediumSize: {
       ContentLength: 24565,
       FilePath: 'medium/...'
    },
    SmallSize: {
        ContentLength: 5464,
        FilePath: 'small/...'
    }
}
```

I was achieving this with small datasets like this, processing the 'original' size first:

```
let out = data.filter(o => o.size === 'original).map(o => {
    return {
        Id: o.id,
        Timestamp: o.timestamp,
        OriginalSize: {
            ContentLength: o.contentLength,
            FilePath: o.filepath
        }
    };
});
data.filter(o => o.size !== 'original').forEach(o => {
    let orig = out.find(function (og) {
        return og.Timestamp === o.timestamp;
    });
    orig[o.size + 'Size'] = {
        ContentLength: o.contentLength,
        FilePath: o.filepath
    };
)
// out now contains the correctly-formatted objects
```

The problem comes with the very large datasets, where I can't load the hundreds of megabytes of JSON into memory all at once. This seems like a great time to use streams, but of course if I read the file in chunks, running .find() on a small array to find the 'original' size won't work. If I scan through the whole file to find originals and then scan through again to add the other sizes to what I've found, I end up with the whole dataset in memory anyway.

I know of [JSONStream](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream), which would be great if I was doing a simple 1-1 remapping of my objects.

Surely I can't be the first one to run into this kind of problem. What solutions have been used in the past? How can I approach this?

Comment: Arent't the objects for the different dimensions always adjacent to each other in the input array?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to match them by their timestamp, not by their id?

Comment: My example may have been misleading. No, unfortunately the objects are not adjacent at all, and could be anywhere in the file. And yes, matching by timestamp is what I want. This is operating on all the records with a certain ID, so it's not too consequential here.

Comment: Is each property on it's own line, as depicted in your question? For example, `id` is on one line, `timestamp` is on the next line, etc.

Comment: No, each object is one one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the trick is to update the database on the fly. If the JSON file is too big for memory, then I expect the resulting set of objects (`out` in your example) is too big for memory too.

In the comments you state the JSON file has one object per line. Therefore using node.js builtin `fs.createReadStream` and `readline` to get each line of the text file. Next process the line (string) into a json object, and finally update the database.

*parse.js*

```
var readline = require('readline');
var fs = require('fs');

var jsonfile = 'text.json';

var linereader = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream(jsonfile)
});

linereader.on('line', function (line) {
  obj = parseJSON(line); // convert line (string) to JSON object

  // check DB for existing id/timestamp
  if ( existsInDB({id:obj.id, timestamp:obj.timestamp}) ) {
    updateInDB(obj); // already exists, so UPDATE
  }
  else { insertInDB(obj); } // does not exist, so INSERT
});


// DUMMY functions below, implement according to your needs

function parseJSON (str) {
  str = str.replace(/,\s*$/, ""); // lose trailing comma
  return eval('(' + str + ')'); // insecure! so no unknown sources
}
function existsInDB (obj) { return true; }
function updateInDB (obj) { console.log(obj); }
function insertInDB (obj) { console.log(obj); }
```

*text.json*

```
{ id: '001', timestamp: '2016-06-02T14:10:53Z', contentLength: 123456, filepath: 'original/...', size: 'original' },
{ id: '001', timestamp: '2016-06-02T14:10:53Z', contentLength: 24565, filepath: 'medium/...', size: 'medium' },
{ id: '001', timestamp: '2016-06-02T14:10:53Z', contentLength: 5464, filepath: 'small/...', size: 'small' }
```

NOTE: I needed to quote the timestamp value to avoid a syntax error. From your question and example script I expect you either don't have this problem or already have this solved, maybe another way.

Also, my implementation of `parseJSON` may be different from how you are parsing the JSON. Plain old `JSON.parse` failed for me due to the properties not being quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Setup some DB instance, that can store JSON documents. MongoDB or PostgreSQL (recently they introduced jsonb data type for storing json documents). Iterate through the old JSON documents and combine them to the new structure, using the DB as the storage - such that you overcome the memory problem.

I'm quite sure that there is no way how to achieve your goal without either a) compromising speed of the process (drastically) or b) creating poor man's DB from scratch (which seems like a bad thing to do :) )